# How can I GET information from Google Analytics Core Reporting API using a service account and no client libraries

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, service-accounts

We need to figure out how to pull page views data using this API [Google analytics core Reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) in a scheduled/robotic way.

I've done some research and service accounts sound like what is needed. I've created one of those and generated a key and downloaded a json file with its details inside.

How do I use the credentials of the service account to make an HTTP request to get page views?

Searching the web has been frustrating because every article assumes you want to use a Google-supported PHP or Python library. In our case we want to make HTTP requests directly.

Is this possible?

Comment: Oh its defiantly possible there is even some documentation  [authorizing requests](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests) pay close attention to how the jwt is built up.  If you get it working i would love to see the code.

Comment: If I've got to write my own code to build a JWT it'd be better for us to look at a nodeJS client library. I've tried to build JWTs using my own code before which was very painful and ultimately unsuccessful - you're not supposed to anyway! Thanks

Comment: Well could have mention that I have been trying to do it on and off manually for more then ten years and always given up.   Thought i would let you come to your own conclusion :)   I have some code for [google drive api](https://www.daimto.com/upload-image-to-google-drive-with-node-js/) with a service account might get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I've done something very similar to the code you've linked to. It was actually very straightforward (~30 lines of code) using the googleapis NodeJS library.